# "Rails application failed to start properly" when trying to create a new issue in Redmine

Tags: redmine, dreamhost

A few weeks ago I had my Dreamhost account deactivated because I forgot to change my credit card information when I switched cards. I had a perfectly operational Redmine installation that went down for about a day.

After reinstating my account, everything works fine except that when I try to create a new issue on this Redmine installation I get:

"Application error
Rails application failed to start properly"

I've tried everything on [this list](http://help.slamdot.com/idx/0/119/Why-am-I-getting-a-Rails-application-failed-to-start-properly-error), but nothing has fixed the issue. Does anyone have any pointers for working through this problem.

I should also mention that the issue does get successfully created and shows up in my issues list.

**EDIT: I just encountered this problem again when adding a note to an issue. The note was successfully saved, but the error message did come up**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to web server logs? Can you set logging level to 'debug' and bring logs here? This would be great.

Comment: It's hosted by Dreamhost, I don't think I can change Apache's LogLevel. The error log, however is empty.

Comment: Without logs, all answers are speculation.

Comment: I'm fine with trying many different ideas. Unfortunately I don't have access to change the log level in apache.

Comment: Operating system, file system, web server, web server module for using ruby(for example, mod_passender) and ruby application are very complex systems with many components, disfunction of any component may cause problems. You can't guess what is wrong without diagnostics. Talk to Dreamhost support about access to logs.